# Cannot read property 'impl' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I wrote some small code in angular js. It works but i get some error "Cannot read property 'impl' of undefined". Does somebody knows what that?

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Validation</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/matchmedia-ng.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-touch.js"></script>
        <script src="js/module.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngTouch','matchmedia-ng']);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'matchmedia',
    function($scope, matchmedia) {
    $scope.desktop = matchmedia.isDesktop();
    $scope.tablet =matchmedia.isTablet()
    $scope.phone = matchmedia.isPhone();
        if($scope.desktop){
            alert("desktop");
        }
        else if($scope.tablet){
            alert("tablet");
        }
        else if($scope.phone){
            alert("phone");
        }
}]);
```

This is an errror:
TypeError {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'impl' of undefined"}message: "Cannot read property 'impl' of undefined"stack: (...)

Comment: Somehow I feel there is some code missing. Can you reproduce it in plunker?

Comment: I copied your code and it is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/hclw4RimIMf4cADq4o0F?p=preview

Comment: working but with an error

Answer (score 1):

Error is coming from plunker addthis api integration, and nothing wrong into your code.

Comment: I had a similar issue after adding a 3rd party extension to Chrome. Removed the extension and the error stopped.